# Dismiss TableSorter Column Selector Widget

Tags: tablesorter

I'm using the Column Selector Widget on Mottie's excellent tablesorter.  It works great!

However, when a user clicks on the button (using CSS Popup only mode), the only way to dismiss the selection modal is to click on the same button again.  This is inconsistent with the rest of my app, which dismisses bootstrap modals when clicking anywhere outside of the modal.

I know I can write an onClick function to monitor the whole body, but I wonder, is there a built-in option that I've missed that will dismiss the column chooser when a user clicks outside the box?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That "Column" button uses a hidden checkbox to show/hide the popup - it's pure HTML & CSS and completely customizable.

If you to modify the current setup, add the following ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/mcn8o3yu/14/)):

HTML (add after the "columnSelectorWrapper")

```
<div id="columnSelectorOverlay"></div>
```

CSS

```
#columnSelectorOverlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  display:none;
}
```

* note: remove the `background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);` setting if you don't want the dark overlay.

Then add the following setting to the `.columnSelector` definition:

```
z-index: 1;
```

Then add this javascript

```
$('#colSelect1').on('change', function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $('#columnSelectorOverlay').show();
  }
});

$('#columnSelectorOverlay').click(function() {
  $('#colSelect1').prop('checked', false);
  $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: Brilliant solution!  Works perfectly.  Many many thanks for the help, and the fantastic tablesorter @Mottie.